# How do I use "with" as a key in a TypedDict?

Tags: python, dictionary, types

I want to use `with` as a key in a `TypedDict` in python 3.10.

I have:

```py
from typing import TypedDict, Optional

class Operation(TypedDict, total=False):
    uses: str
    with: Optional[ActionCheckout]
```

But my IDE says I cannot do this?

[image: idecomplain]

Comment: @Wondercricket is there no way to define this dictionary in a different way that would allow me to use `with` as a key? because you can use `with` as a key if I didnt care about typing it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You won't be able to use the declarative syntax, as `with` (being a hard keyword defined by the grammar) is not a valid identifier; use the [functional syntax](https://peps.python.org/pep-0589/#alternative-syntax) instead.

```
Operation = TypedDict('Operation', {'uses': str, 'with': Optional[ActionCheckout]})
```

---

This is specifically addressed in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict):

> The functional syntax should also be used when any of the keys are not valid [identifiers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers), for example because they are keywords

Comment: It hints `dict`s; `with` is just a key, not an attribute. Are you thinking of the similar issue with `namedtuple`?

Comment: This worked exactly how I was looking thank you @chepner!!!

Comment: (Deleting my comment; I went a little overboard contrasting `type` with `_TypeDictMeta` :))